# How can I hide the HTML in a gravity form field from appearing in te confirmation message?

Tags: html, css, forms, gravity

Basically I am using a radio button field and have added HTML in the field itself to link and a preview plugin class like so

Field: Sedan, 3-passenger `<a href="http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/carimg.png" class="thumbsniper" target="_blank">View</a>`

And this works fine except when the form gives confirmation message using the corresponding field's merge tag {vehicle you would like} it shows the entry and all the HTML as a string as well, which obviously is a problem. How can I fix this issue and have the confirmation treat the html as such?  Do I have to add all of this html as a class instead and apply it to the unique entry css instead of inline or is there some way to mess with the merge tags or with minimal css changes to the confirmation message classes?

The stuff in the confirmation field in the form UI (using inline styles to test for now, I know its not the best way but either way doesn't really solve my problem):

```
<p style="text-align:center;"><strong style="font-size:16px;"> Thank you!!!</strong>
We will send you an <strong style="color:#8E0F0F;">Email Quote</strong> within the next <strong style="color:#8E0F0F;">30 minutes.</strong>*
                      *Subject to Driver Availability.
<strong style="color:#8E0F0F;">Important Warning: When we send you an Email Quote, it might end up in your SPAM/JUNK EMAIL folder, so please double check that folder.</strong></p>
<strong>Submitted:</strong>{date_mdy}
<strong>Status:</strong> Waiting to be accepted by a Service Provider.
<strong>Pick Up:</strong>  On{Pick-Up On::7}, at {At::8} at
{Address (Street Address):9.1} {Address (City):9.3}
<strong>Drop Off:</strong> {Drop-Off Airport/Cruise Port:10}
<strong>Passenger or group name:</strong> {Passenger/Group Name:15}
<strong>Number of Passengers:</strong> {Number of People in the Group:16}
<strong>Contact Person:</strong>{Contact Person's Name:17}
<strong>Quote will be emailed to:</strong>{Contact Person's Email:18}
<strong>Rate:</strong> {What Type of Vehicle Would You Like?:6} Quote to be Provided. <strong>15% Online Discount Active!</strong>
```

Extra question on the same form, is there any way to attach a timestamp to the {date_mdy} merge tag so it actually includes the time of submission in the confirmation and not just the date? Obviously the hook exists since entry time is shown in the WP backend but I don't know how to go about getting it to work here. Thank you for any replies, this car reservation form has been a headache.

Comment: Can you show [some of] the code which displays the confirmation message?

Comment: Sure, but its just the gravity forms merge tags and text, I'll edit.

Comment: And I assume you have HTML-Enabled option checked?

Comment: I also see something that says to Uncheck "Disable Auto Formatting"...

Comment: HTML is enabled, since it reads it fine in the actual field where I use it, just not when pulling it into the confirmation message. Disable auto formatting doesn't do anything either. My problem is the html being parsed as a string when going from the field it is in originally to the confirmation output. Maybe some simple function can fix this but I'm not good enough with php/js to figure it out :(

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know Gravity Forms, I'm just getting my answers via Google and the Gravity Forms website. Have you tried asking them on their support/forums page? Not to redirect you away from StackOverflow, but they would definitely be able to help you.